# How to search for a post of mine answered by a particular user with some word in his reply?

Tags: support

I want to find a post of mine, answered by a user e.g. Gilles, with "encoding" in his reply. Can I do that either on the main site or on data.SE site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the main site's [search options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching) are advanced enough to let you find posts by a particular user that are answers to questions by another particular user. It's pretty easy with the data explorer though: http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/546618?AnswererId=885&BodyText=encoding&UserId=674